# Participles at the beginning of a sentence used adjectivally

Tags: participles, adjectivals

Would the adjectival use of the participle ENGAGED in the subordinate clause be correct to describe the students in the MAIN clause?

> **Engaged** in a broad spectrum of speaking and listening activities appropriate for their level, using a wide-range of materials from various sources, the students will be encouraged to get out of their comfort zones.

Comment: It's correct, but it's bad style to have two adjectival adjunct phrases in a row describing the same noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [*Engaged in a broad spectrum of speaking and listening activities*
> *appropriate for their level, using a wide-range of materials from*
> *various sources*]*, the students will be encouraged to get out of their*
> *comfort zones.*

I take "engaged" to be an adjective here, so the expression "engaged in a broad spectrum of speaking and listening activities ... " is an adjective phrase functioning as a predicative adjunct.

It's predicative because it relates to a predicand ("the students") and it's an adjunct because it is an optional item detached from the rest of the clause.

Comment: I understand your explanation, but I'm not sure if it implies that it's fine to use it as it is used in this sentence. I did intended to use it as an adjective.

Comment: @Lena I said in my answer that it's an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have chosen a hard-to-understand phrasing.

The (passive) subject of the verb "Engaged" is "students" but it is so far from the verb that it took me two or three readings to begin to make sense of it.

A complete structural re-write is needed.  Place the main clause at the start, and perhaps use several linked sentences.

Comment: I appreaciate your reply. However, if I want to keep the same structure, could I use ENGAGING instead to make the sentence be understood more easily, and if so, would I need to use a preposition such as BY with it?

Comment: The problem is not the word, the problem is the structure. You can't fix the structure by changing the word.  A simple fix would be "The students will be encouraged to .... *by being* engaged in a broad ..."  It means that we aren't left waiting for a the subject.

Comment: You might consider "engaged" to be an adjective.